# Access Instance variable on Native UI Component from React Native

Tags: swift, react-native, swift3

I have a Native UI Component in `Swift` and I need to be able to access the value of one of its `variable` from React Native side.

For Example, my `Swift` component contains the following `var`:

```
open class AnyNativeClass: UIView {
   open var clippingStartTime = 5.46
}
```

The value of `clippingStartTime` can change. I need to be able to know the value of `clippingStartTime` from JS. I don't need to know when it changed, I just need to be able to retrieve the value when I need to.